# Whats wrong with my Hermite Interpolation in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, interpolation, numerical-analysis, hermite, polynomial-approximations

## Hermite Interpolation woes

I am trying to find the Newton Dividing Differences for the function and derivative values of a given set of x's. I'm running into serious problems with my code working for tiny examples, but failing on bigger one's. As is clearly visible, my answers are very much larger than they original function values.

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
program inter
  implicit none
  integer ::n,m
  integer ::i
  real(kind=8),allocatable ::xVals(:),fxVals(:),newtonDivDiff(:),dxVals(:),zxVals(:),zdxVals(:),zfxVals(:)
  real(kind=8) ::Px
  real(kind=8) ::x


  Open(Unit=8,File="data/xVals")
  Open(Unit=9,File="data/fxVals")
  Open(Unit=10,File="data/dxVals")

  n = 4 ! literal number of data pts
  m = n*2+1

  !after we get the data points allocate the space
  allocate(xVals(0:n))
  allocate(fxVals(0:n))
  allocate(dxVals(0:n))
  allocate(newtonDivDiff(0:n))

  !allocate the zvalue arrays
  allocate(zxVals(0:m))
  allocate(zdxVals(0:m))
  allocate(zfxVals(0:m))

  !since the size is the same we can read in one loop
  do i=0,n
    Read(8,*) xVals(i)
    Read(9,*) fxVals(i)
    Read(10,*) dxVals(i)
  end do  
 ! contstruct the z illusion 
  do i=0,m,2
    zxVals(i) = xVals(i/2)
    zxVals(i+1) = xVals(i/2)

    zdxVals(i) = dxVals(i/2)
    zdxVals(i+1) = dxVals(i/2)

    zfxVals(i) = fxVals(i/2)
    zfxVals(i+1) = fxVals(i/2)

  end do
  !slightly modified business as usual
  call getNewtonDivDiff(zxVals,zdxVals,zfxVals,newtonDivDiff,m)
  do i=0,n 
    call evaluatePolynomial(m,newtonDivDiff,xVals(i),Px,zxVals)
    print*, xVals(i) ,Px
  end do
  close(8)
  close(9)
  close(10)
  stop

  deallocate(xVals,fxVals,dxVals,newtonDivDiff,zxVals,zdxVals,zfxVals)
end program inter

subroutine getNewtonDivDiff(xVals,dxVals,fxVals,newtonDivDiff,n)
    implicit none
    integer ::i,k
    integer, intent(in) ::n
    real(kind=8), allocatable,dimension(:,:) ::table
    real(kind=8),intent(in) ::xVals(0:n),dxVals(0:n),fxVals(0:n)
    real(kind=8), intent(inout) ::newtonDivDiff(0:n)
    allocate(table(0:n,0:n))

    table = 0.0d0

    do i=0,n
        table(i,0) = fxVals(i)
    end do

    do k=1,n
        do i = k,n
            if( k .eq. 1 .and. mod(i,2) .eq. 1) then
                table(i,k) = dxVals(i)
            else
                table(i,k) = (table(i,k-1) - table(i-1,k-1))/(xVals(i) - xVals(i-k))
            end if
        end do 
    end do

    do i=0,n
        newtonDivDiff(i) = table(i,i)
        !print*, newtonDivDiff(i)
    end do
    deallocate(table)
end subroutine getNewtonDivDiff

subroutine evaluatePolynomial(n,newtonDivDiff,x,Px,xVals)
    implicit none
    integer,intent(in) ::n
    real(kind=8),intent(in) ::newtonDivDiff(0:n),xVals(0:n)
    real(kind=8),intent(in) ::x
    real(kind=8), intent(out) ::Px
    integer ::i
    Px = newtonDivDiff(n)
    do i=n,1,-1
        Px  = Px * (x-  xVals(i-1)) + newtonDivDiff(i-1)
    end do
end subroutine evaluatePolynomial
```

### Values

x     f(x)    f'(x)

1.16,  1.2337,  2.6643

1.32,  1.6879,  2.9989

1.48,  2.1814,  3.1464

1.64,  2.6832,  3.0862

1.8,   3.1553,  2.7697

### Output

1.1599999999999999        62.040113431002474

1.3200000000000001        180.40121445431600

1.4800000000000000        212.36319446149312

1.6399999999999999        228.61845650513027

1.8000000000000000        245.11610836104515

Comment: I can't reproduce any problem with some synthetic data. Could you post your input files in the format the program reads them?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to upload my input files but my formatting is very simple. Each file has one column with the numers on a seperate line.
[Here's a link](http://pastebin.com/vGMq4vv8) to the basic formatting with the filename at the top of each.

Comment: You can't upload them, you can cut and paste the content. Easier for us to cut and paste than having to play with the columns and commas.

Answer (score 4):

You are accessing array `newtonDivDiff` out of bounds.

You are first allocating it as `0:n` (main program's `n`) then you are passing to subroutine `getNewtonDivDiff` as `0:n` (the subroutine's `n`)  but you pass `m` (m=n*2+1) to the argument `n`. That means you tell the subroutine that the array has bounds `0:m` which is `0:9`, but it has only bounds `0:4`.

It is quite difficult to debug the program as it stands, I had to use `valgrind`. If you move your subroutines to a module and change the dummy arguments to assumed shape arrays `(:,:)` then the bound checking in gfortran (`-fcheck=all`) will catch the error.

Other notes:

`kind=8` is ugly, 8 can mean different things for different compilers. If you want 64bit variables, you can use `kind=real64` (`real64` comes from module `iso_fortran_env` in Fortran 2008) or use `selected_real_kind()` ([Fortran 90 kind parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter))

You do not have to deallocate your local arrays in the subroutines, they are deallocated automatically.

Your `deallocate` statement in the main program is after the stop statement, it will never be executed. I would just delete the `stop`, there is no reason to have it.